# Validate interface of function call

Tags: typescript, interface, typechecking

I have a the following code:

```
myArray: { value: string; name: string; }[]; 

orderFunction (a, b) {
    if (a.wrong > b.wrong) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

myArray.sort(orderFuncion);
```

The above code should give an error as the elements in the array don't have the **wrong** property, but it does not

The definition of **sort** is correct:

```
/**
  * Sorts an array.
  * @param compareFn The name of the function used to determine the order of the elements. If omitted, the elements are sorted in ascending, ASCII character order.
  */
sort(compareFn?: (a: T, b: T) => number): this;
```

but orderFunction is typed as (any any)

How can I make typescript validate it automatically ?

Comment: A side note: the sort function doesn't handle equality. So, it will falsely consider some cases as unequal possibly leading to incorrect order which is going to be difficult to find and debug.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, of course you are right. This is not my real code, I skipped most of it since it is not relevant to the question. Also, the elements of my array have more properties ....

Answer (score 0):

the paramaters `a` and `b` are both typed `any` because you haven't annotated them with a type.

```
orderFunction (a: { value: string; name: string; }, b: { value: string; name: string; }) {
    if (a.wrong > b.wrong) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

or in a generic way

```
orderFunction<T> (a: T, b: T) {
    if (a.wrong > b.wrong) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

will give you the desired error because the type `{ value: string; name: string; }` does not have a `wrong` property.

If you don't want implicit `any` to be a thing you can set `noImplicitAny: true` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what I want is to get this automatically. Typescript knows that the sort function has the type (a: T, b: T) => number, and knows that myArray elements have this type, but it is not using this data.

Comment: To clarify, `.sort(orderFunction)` will not make `orderFunction` know the type of the paramaters, if they're not generic or annotated.

Comment: @vals then you probably should [disallow implicit `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny). This means that you'll be mandated to add a type for `a` and `b` otherwise you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: If I use the generic function, how should i use the sort function , to handle the type ?